# Using \pi in siunitx macros with unicode-math

Tags: symbols, siunitx, unicode-math

I want to be able to use `\pi` in the `siunitx` macros, e.g. `\num{\pi/3}`, while using `unicode-math`. What do I need to change in order for this to work?

(It works without `unicode-math`. `input-symbols` does not help.)

```latex
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\num{\pi/3}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: `Missing character: There is no  (U+1D70B) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Aha! (I missed that warning, since TeXstudio doesn't recognize it..)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
 \num{\pi/3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works! However, the only place `mathrm` is mentioned in the documentation is in a table of old option names from version 1. It recommends using the newer `math-rm`. Is `mathrm=sym` equivalent to `math-rm=\symnormal`?

Comment: did you look in the right documentation? That is an unicode-math setting.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer there is documentation?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oops.That makes more sense. I didn't look carefully enough and used it as an option to `siunitx`, which works, too.

Answer (score 2):

Ulrike Fischer already provided an answer for `unicode-math`, and I’d recommend you use that when you can and PDFTeX when you have to.  In case you have to, here is a solution that gives you an upright π (correct according to ISO) with PDFTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[OMLmathrm, rmdefault=mdput]{isomath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\num{\pi/3}

\end{document}
```

This sets up `\mathrm` to use the OML encoding, which supports lowercase Greek letters.  As of 2020, there are only three OML-encoded upright font families: `mdbch` (Math Design Charter), `mdugm` (Math Design Garamond), and `mdput` (Math Design Utopia).  For this example, I loaded `\usepackage{fourier}` and `mdput` to match it.

It is also possible to configure `siunitx` to recognize `\muppi` from `unicode-math`, or `\uppi` from certain other packages (but not `unicode-math`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[math-rm]{siunitx}  

\sisetup{ input-symbols = . \muppi }

\begin{document}
 
\num{\muppi/3}

\end{document}
```